# How to create an application to poll 10 JMX URI and store in DB in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-scheduled

How to create an application to poll 50 JMX URI and store the mbeans in DB.
I have created a class which will connect to jmx server and fetch the mbeans value.
My question is how to trigger my created class and method to continues polling.
Moreover, I need two function to start and stop this polling anytime.

What can I use - Spring Scheduler, Spring Integration and how or should I create different class having thread and infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Spring Integration and its JMX [Tree Polling Channel Adapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#tree-polling-channel-adapter).

Answer (score 0):

With Spring Scheduler (`@Schedule` annotation) it is easy to have a method that is invoked (for example) every minute. But it is not possible* to change (disable) that scheduling.

Anyway you could:

- use the quarz-framework directly, then you could change the scheduling, or
- do implement a dirty (but easy) hack:

*Let the schueduler run, but disable the invocation of the real polling method:*

```
private volantile boolean pollingEnabled;  

@Schedule(fixedRate=1000)
public void pollTrigger() {
    if (pollingEnabled) {
        doPolling();
    }
}
```

**more precise: to my knowlege there is no easy way*